# How do I go about resizing a column in Omni Outliner?

Tags: formatting, omnioutliner

I've added some columns to Omni Outliner, and can't seem to find the control that allows me to adjust their width. The drag and drop control on the side of each column resizes the entire table. I bet there's something obvious I'm missing - anyone know off the top of their head?